# CakePHP 3 new ORM MySQL keyword errors

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

Cake3 ORM Question: Is there a trick to avoid MySQL keyword errors in SQL strings?

I get a "1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax" error when I try to update my users table.

`UPDATE users SET group = 'admin', modified = '2016-06-27 15:45:02' WHERE id = 2`

How can I add the table name **users.group** to the SQL string to avoid the keyword error?

Controller.action (efault)

```
public function edit($id = null)
{
    $user = $this->Users->get($id);
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The Entry has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The Entry could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('user', 'contacts', 'userLists'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
}
```

Comment: You should show the code that you are using which actually produces this query, as possible solutions depend on that.

Comment: yes, I totally understand your comment. But my problem is not a code problem. It is the ORM what produces the update SQL without the table name. That causes the SQL syntax error, because GROUP is a MySQL keyword.

Comment: Sure, I got that, but there are multiple ways to make the ORM/query-builder to generate that query, and depending on the how, the problem can be solved in different ways. You could for example have used `Query::update()`.

Comment: The duplicate uses bake, but it's the same problem, and the same solution applies here.

Comment: Thanks. Last question to this issue. Where do I "enable this feature at runtime" ?

Comment: Via the DB drivers `autoQuoting()` method.Have you checked the linked docs?

Comment: In the moment I put the dynamic database config change in the edit/add action of the controller. This is a working solution. I was just wondering if there is a better place (model callback?!).

Comment: Oh ok, I somehow read this as "_how do I ..._". Well, depends on where/when you want the auto-quoting to be applied, ie whether it should apply to a specific model only, or only in a specific controller/action (to all models), or to all models at all time, etc... I could imagine applying it to a specific model only could be problematic.